# Laptop shuts down with external fan

Tags: laptop, cooling

I'm trying to add an external fan to my laptop that blows air either into the inlet vent or onto the CPU and GPU with the case open. But when it's too powerful (eg. a hair dryer set to cold) and the computer is under heavy load, it shuts down. Why would it do that?

Temperatures are lower than normal and it runs faster until it suddenly turns off.

My guess is that maybe the temperature sensors for shutting down are different from the ones for adjusting the clock speed so one part is overheating even worse due to running faster.

Comment: My guess is that the blast of cold air affects the heat transfer from the CPU through the heat pipe causing the CPU to overheat.

Comment: can you take some pictures and add them

Comment: What details do you want to see in the pictures?